# Linkedin second degree connections API

Tags: php, codeigniter, linkedin-api

I got the linkedin authenticated user's profile information and connection details as per the codeigniter/linkedin api method.But my final need is to get the connections of my connections.The linkedin documentation says that if we have the 'r_network' permission we will get the 1st and 2nd degree connections,but I couldn't. Please suggest a solution for fetching the second degree connections.The following is my code.

```
$profile_connections = $this->linkedin->profile('~/connections:(id,first-name,last-name,picture-url,industry,location,public-profile-url,positions:(company:(name)))');
$profile_connections = json_decode($profile_connections['linkedin']);

foreach ($profile_connections->values as $connections){
            $sub_connections = $this->linkedin->profile("url=".urlencode($connections->publicProfileUrl)."/connections:(id,first-name,last-name,picture-url,industry,location)");
            $sub_connections = json_decode($sub_connections['linkedin']);
        }
```

But while fetching the 2nd degree connection got an error message like "Access to connections denied".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Quoted* from [linkedin developer forum](https://developer-programs.linkedin.com/comment/19128#comment-19128):

**API** to be more explicit in terms of what is returned by the API.
     **Only 1st degree connections** are returned by the **Connections API**.
     While the **r_network** member permissions does grant your application access to
     **both 1st and 2nd degree** connections (*this member permissions is required for both Connections API and People Search API*), 
    it's only through **the People Search API** which allows you access to **2nd degree connections.** The **Connections API** has always only been **restricted to 1st degree connections.**

So, that's pretty much your problem.

Comment: Can You give any example use People search Api,

Comment: take a look [here](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/sample-code-people-search)
and for codeigniter [here](http://thinkdiff.net/linkedin/integrate-linkedin-api-in-your-site/) is another example