# Linkedin get user's connection from id

Tags: ios, iphone, linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I am developing an iOS app, I want to integrate linkedin
This is how I want to use linked in to my app.

I am logged in from User A account , now I want coonection detail of User B , How to get that detail. I have read on linked in document anout this api

[https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/{id}/connections?modified=new](https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/%7Bid%7D/connections?modified=new)

But this is not working. I am getting this error

```
**<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<error>
  <status>403</status>
  <timestamp>1426852256729</timestamp>
  <request-id>544WHZL91V</request-id>
  <error-code>0</error-code>
  <message>Access to connections denied</message>
</error>**
```

Can anyone please advice me on this?

Here I am using FACEBOOK tag to get more people attention this, I need this on immediate basis.

Comment: so, just becase you need the answer "immediately", you include completely unrelated tags? seriously?

Comment: @luschn if you dont want to help me then no worries but dont give me this excuse

Comment: where did i say that i don´t want to help? i am just saying, it´s a very bad move to include unrelated tags to get more attention.

Comment: @luschn I am doing this for iPhone app that's why I have used ios and iphone tag...that is completely relavent

Comment: you did not mention ios/iphone once in your question, and it´s not at all relevant for the question itself.

Comment: @luschn ok thanx for giving attention to my question...now may i know any of your suggestion for this

Comment: what exactly do you want to get? is user B connected to user A?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73417/discussion-between-vivek-and-luschn).

Answer (score 0):

You can only get the first degree connections for authorized users, and the second degree connections - but only with approvel from LinkedIn afaik. And you have to use the People Search API to get second degree connections, it´s a bit more complicated than the Connections API.

More information:

- [Linkedin second degree connections API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14230502/linkedin-second-degree-connections-api)
- https://developer-programs.linkedin.com/documents/connections-api
- https://developer-programs.linkedin.com/documents/people-search-api

If you want to show connections between two users, there is only one way i can think of:

- Both users must authorize your App
- You need to store all their first level connections
- Whenever the user comes back to your App, you need to update the connections
- You can compare the connections directly in your database

Comment: but it will be complex process if we update at all the time user return to the app...If I want to set any period for updateing connection automatically then can you suggest me any period with reason.?

Comment: i believe access tokens are valid for 60 days, so you could store and reuse them but after 60 days they will not work anymore and you need to be careful with api limits too.

Comment: You should also note that as of May 12th, 2015, access to this information via the API is changing.  See this blog post for more details:  https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/posts/2015/developer-program-changes